# Running Apache mod_php and mod_fastcgi in seperate vhosts on one Apache server

Tags: php, apache, virtualhost, mod-fastcgi, mod-php

So, I need to run multiple php apps/sites on one server. One or many should run using apache and mod_php5, and one or many should be able to run using mod_fastcgi and php-fpm. The mod_php5 ones are currently fine, and the fastcgi ones work if i disable mod_php5, but I'm having difficulty getting them to work at the same time.

I think this can be achieved using some combination of filesmatch, if.mod_fastcgi and if.mod_actions in apache, but I cant work out what it is. We can install any apache modules required to do this if needed.

Super bonus points if there is a different version of the vhost for Apache 2.2 or less and you have that snippet too, or at least know what I should do

Im not going to post the entire vhosts i have as i know they're wrong, but the first, default, mod_php based vhosts are looking like so...

```
#NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80     < Apache 2.2 or less    
 <VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
   ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
   ServerName some.site.tld
   DocumentRoot /var/www/some/site/
   <Directory /var/www/some/site/>
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
     Require all granted
#               Order deny,allow     < Apache 2.2 or less
#               Allow from all     < Apache 2.2 or less
   </Directory>
   ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
   CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
 </VirtualHost>
```

Ideally, I'd like these to remain untouched, and that we can add more if we need more of these.

The outcome I would like, is to be able to drop in new vhosts configured for mod_php using something like the first configuration, and also drop in vhosts like the following for fast cgi.

```
# NameVirtualHost 0.0.0.0:80  < Apache 2.2 or Less
<VirtualHost 0.0.0.0:80>
   ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
   ServerName some.application.tld
   DocumentRoot /opt/some/app/dir/
   ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
   CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
   <IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
     #     php_admin_flag engine off    < I tried to use this to disable PHP
     AddType application/x-httpd-fastphp5 .php
     Action application/x-httpd-fastphp5 /php5-fcgi
     Alias /php5-fcgi /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi_someapp
     FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi_someapp -socket /var/run/php5-fpm_ptbuild.sock -pass-header Authorization
     <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews ExecCGI
       Require all granted
     </Directory>
     <Directory /opt/some/app/dir/>
       #Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews ExecCGI
       Require all granted
     </Directory>         
   </IfModule>
#    I tried to use the below alongside mod_php, didnt work
#    <IfModule mod_php5.c>
#        php_admin_flag engine off
#        AddType application/x-httpd-fastphp5 .php
#       <Directory /opt/some/app/dir/>
#               Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews ExecCGI
#               Require all granted
#       </Directory>
#    </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

If you could post the second vhost, or tell me what I'm doing wrong, thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We've got a similar setup on our servers to run 2 versions of PHP, but under the same virtual host. Essentially it's for an old version of the software while transitioning to a new version - 1 runs through the original Apache config and the other through CGI.
Ours is directory based, so slightly different but I think it should work for your situation still.

First, we have the fastCGI config in a separate file */etc/apache2/mods-enabled/fastcgi.conf*:

```
<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
    #  AddHandler fastcgi-script .fcgi
    FastCgiWrapper /usr/lib/apache2/suexec
    FastCgiIpcDir /var/lib/apache2/fastcgi
    FastCgiConfig -idle-timeout 110 -killInterval 120 -pass-header HTTP_AUTHORIZATION -autoUpdate
    ScriptAlias /php-fcgi/ /var/www/cgi-bin/
</IfModule>
```

Then, in the virtual host config itself we have this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sitename
    ...
    # Original non-CGI site
    <Directory "/sites/webroot/site1/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    # FastCGI version
    <Directory "/sites/webroot/site2/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
        AddHandler php-cgi .php
        Action php-cgi /php-fcgi/php562.fcgi
        <FilesMatch "\.php$">
            SetHandler php-cgi
        </FilesMatch>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I think the key thing that is required for you is the **AddHandler** and **SetHandler** directives which make it work. Then you should be able to add as many separate sites either with different directories or individual virtual hosts.

Comment: Thanks buddy, its all about the handlers. Cheers

Comment: Good to hear it worked :) 
We had to do a lot of stuffing around to get this all working with PHPFarm as well.